# Transfer textbox value from Word Document to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am creating a report where i have to transfer information from a table from Word document into excel with just 1 click of a button using macro.

I have already did the coding of it and it works. However i decided to make it better by limiting the amount of characters in one part of the table. So i used TextBox (Active X control) and i tried using the same code but it did not work this time round.

This is the code that i used to pull the code from word to excel:

```
If CELLER.RowIndex = 2 And CELLER.ColumnIndex = 2 Then Sheet2.Cells(LL, COL_EQUIP).Value2 = Application.Trim(Replace(Replace(CELLER.Range.Text, Chr(13), vbNullString), Chr(7), vbNullString))
```

Celler refers to the table im trying to get the information from. The problem im trying to edit is **CELLER.Range.Text**. Since now it isnt a text anymore but a text inside a textbox. what should i do about it?

Comment: use the textbox value

Comment: `Application.Trim(CELLER.Range.InlineShapes(1).OLEFormat.Object.Text)`

Comment: thanks everyone. i am able to solve it